# How to bind a gridview from two random columns from two tables

Tags: c#

I have two tables in my database, one for photo and other for post.

Now like facebook I have to show these photos and posts together in a gridview.

It is not necessary to post post and photo together so when someone post a post then it show only post and if someone upload a photo then it should only photo like facebook wall displays.

So how to bind data like this in a gridview.

Problem is that when i bind the data in gridview in label and image field then it repeats and show photo and post repeatedly. I want to show only post or photo one at a time in one row of gridview.

How to do that? Please help me

Comment: not very clear what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a datasource (ie a collection of objects that includes both images and text : one per item)

```
public class Post
{
     public Image Photo { get; private set; }

     public string Text { get; private set; }

     public Post(Image originalPost)
     {
         Photo = originalPost;
     }

     public Post(string originalPost)
     {
         Text= originalPost;
     }
}
```

Construct a List<Post> and pass it as the datasource of your GridView.

To solve the problem of displaying text and photo in the same column, the answer requires that you specify the display technology used (WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF, Windows Store ...)